# 'ImportError: No module named webappdjango.contrib' django1.10

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

In a Django  tutorial, I am stuck at the integration of 'view.py' file to the localhost server:

python manage.py runserver

When running this, I get the error: `ImportError: No module named webappdjango.contrib`

I am using Python 2.7 and Django 1.10.1

In the shell i am getting this error-

> [  Unhandled exception in thread started by  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
>   line 228, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py",
>   line 117, in inner_run
>       autoreload.raise_last_exception()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
>   line 251, in raise_last_exception
>       six.reraise(*_exception)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
>   line 228, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/**init**.py", line 27,
>   in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line
>   85, in populate
>       app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line
>   120, in create
>       mod = import_module(mod_path)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name) ImportError: No module named webappdjango.contrib ]

Comment: You sure you have `webappdjango` in your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: You are missing the comma after `'webapp'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.